# Inequality $\frac{a^{2}}{b} + \frac{b^{2}}{a} \ge 2 \frac{a^{k+1} + b^{k+1}}{a^{k} + b^{k}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, inequality, optimization, contest-math

If $k$ is real numbers, find the largest $k$ such that the inequality

$$ \frac{a^{2}}{b} + \frac{b^{2}}{a} \ge 2 \frac{a^{k+1} + b^{k+1}}{a^{k} + b^{k}} $$

is true for all $a,b$ positive real numbers.

---

**Attempt:**

Notice that we will always have equality when $a=b$.

---

$$ \frac{a^{2}}{b} + \frac{b^{2}}{a} = \frac{a^{3} + b^{3}}{ab}$$

and since $a^{2} + b^{2} \ge 2ab $, then

$$ \frac{a^{3} + b^{3}}{ab} \ge 2\frac{a^{3} + b^{3}}{a^{2} + b^{2}} $$

So $k=2$ satisfies the inequality. But is $k=2$ the largest?

I also have the information:

$$ \frac{a^{k+2} + b^{k+2}}{a^{k+1} + b^{k+1}} \ge \frac{a^{k+1} + b^{k+1}}{a^{k} + b^{k}} $$

by $C.S$.

If $k=3$ satisfies the inequality, then

$$ (a^{3} + b^{3})(a^{3} + b^{3}) \ge 2 (a^{4} + b^{4})ab $$

$$ a^{6} + a^{3} b^{3} + b^{3} a^{3} + b^{6} \ge 2 a^{5}b + 2 a b^{5} $$

$$ a^{6} + a^{3} b^{3} + b^{3} a^{3} + b^{6} - 2 a^{5}b - 2 a b^{5} \ge 0 $$

$WLOG$, let $b > a$. Setting $b=2^{4},a=2^{3}$, then

$$2^{18} + 2^{9} 2^{12} + 2^{12} 2^{9} + 2^{24} - 2 \cdot 2^{15} 2^{4} - 2 \cdot 2^{3} 2^{20} \ge 0$$
$$ 2^{18} + 2^{22} + 2^{24} - 2^{20} - 2^{24}  \ge 0 $$
$$ 2^{18}(1 + 2^{4}  - 2^{2}) \ge 0 $$
which is still true.

Comment: I'm confused as to the question you are asking here

Comment: Just because your application of CS resulted in a false inequality doesn't necessarily mean the original inequality is false.  In fact I think $k=3, 4$ both work fine. $k>4$ may fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $k=4$ we obtain:
$$\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{b^2}{a}\geq\frac{2(a^5+b^5)}{a^4+b^4}$$ it's
$$(a+b)(a^2+ab+b^2)(a-b)^4\geq0.$$
We'll prove that $$\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{b^2}{a}\geq\frac{2(a^{k+1}+b^{k+1})}{a^k+b^k}$$ is wrong for any $k>4$.

Let $a=xb$.

Thus, our inequality is equivalent to
$$x^2+\frac{1}{x}\geq\frac{2(x^{k+1}+1)}{x^k+1}$$ or  $f(x)\geq0,$ where
$$f(x)=x^{k+3}-2x^{k+2}+x^k+x^3-2x+1.$$
Now, $$f'(x)=(k+3)x^{k+2}-2(k+2)x^{k+1}+kx^{k-1}+3x^2-2$$ and
$$f''(x)=(k+3)(k+2)x^{k+1}-2(k+2)(k+1)x^k+k(k-1)x^{k-2}+6x,$$ which gives
$$f''(1)=8-2k<0.$$
Thus, $f'$ decreases on $[1,1+\epsilon(k)]$ and since $f'(1)=0,$ we see that $f'(x)<0$ on $(1,1+\epsilon(k)).$

Thus, $f$ decreases on $[1,1+\epsilon(k)]$ and since $f(1)=0,$ we see that $f(x)<0$ for $1<x<1+\epsilon(k)$.

Id est, our inequality is wrong for any $k>4$, which says that $4$ is a maximal value of $k$, for which our inequality is true.

Answer (score 1):

I also find $k=3,4$ both work well. generally, let $x=\frac{b}{a}$ rewrite this inequality

$$f(x)=x^{-1}+x^2+x^{k-1}+x^{k+2}-2x^{k+1}\ge2$$

but for $f(x)$ always holds $f(1)=2$ and $f'(1)=0$, which imply $x=1$ is an extrema, as well the balance point, the lowest point for suitable $k$, where if $k$ can make $f(x)$ is stable balanced at $x=1$, otherwise if $x=1$ is not stable, will make $f(1)$ is a point just holds $f'(1)=0$ but not the minima of whole function, and this critical condition is

$$f''(1)<0$$

solved as

$$2k-8>0\quad\text{or}\quad k>4$$

So the largest $k=4$

This may help you understand what I mean about balance point for $f(x,k)$

[image: Function f(x,k)]

Additionally

$$\begin{aligned}
\left(\frac{a^{2}}{b}+\frac{b^{2}}{a}\right)(a^{k}+b^{k})
& = a^{k-1}b^2+\frac{a^{k+2}}{b}+b^{k-1}a^2+\frac{b^{k+2}}{a}\\
& = a^{k-1}b^2+\frac{a^{k+2}}{2b}+\frac{a^{k+2}}{2b}+b^{k-1}a^2+\frac{b^{k+2}}{2a}+\frac{b^{k+2}}{2a}\\
& \ge 3\left(a^{k-1}b^2 \cdot \frac{a^{k+2}}{2b}\cdot \frac{a^{k+2}}{2b}\right)^{1/3}+3\left(b^{k-1}a^2 \cdot \frac{b^{k+2}}{2a} \cdot \frac{b^{k+2}}{2a}\right)^{1/3}\\
& = 3\left(\tfrac1{4}\right)^{1/3} (a^{k+1}+b^{k+1})
\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 0):

*Partial work*
We can show $k=4$ works.  i.e. to show:
$$\frac{a^2}b + \frac{b^2}a \geqslant 2\frac{a^5+b^5}{a^4+b^4}$$
$$\iff (a^3+b^3)(a^4+b^4)\geqslant 2ab(a^5+b^5)$$
$$\iff a^7-2a^6b+a^4b^3+a^3b^4-2ab^6+b^7 \geqslant 0$$
WLOG setting $a = bt$, where $t\in (0,1)$, we get equivalently to show 
$$t^7-2t^6+t^4+t^3-2t+1 \geqslant 0$$ 
The derivative of the LHS is $(t-1)^3(7t^3+9t^2+6t+2)$ which is negative in $(0, 1)$, hence LHS is monotone decreasing from $1$ when $t=1$ to $0$ when $t=1$, hence proven.

Still to prove $k>4$ does not work...